# How to add mutiple progress views to a timer?

Tags: ios, swift

*here is all of the code that I am using for this project. I have four progress views and when the first end an alarm goes off and then the next start eminently and then goes to the next and then to the fourth one where the timer ends after that and the timer goes off one more time and then the timers stop.*

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    

    
    }

    @IBAction func btnPressed4(_ sender: Any) {
        
            let currentDateTime = Date()
           let formatter = DateFormatter()
           formatter.timeStyle = .short
          let dateTimeString = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
        timePrint4.text = dateTimeString
        btnPressed4.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func btnPressed3(_ sender: Any) {
        
            let currentDateTime = Date()
           let formatter = DateFormatter()
           formatter.timeStyle = .short
          let dateTimeString = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
        timePrint3.text = dateTimeString
        btnPressed3.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    
    
    
    @IBAction func btnPressed2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
        let currentDateTime = Date()
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
       formatter.timeStyle = .short
      let dateTimeString = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
        timePrint2.text = dateTimeString
        btnPressed2.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @IBAction func btnPressed1(_ sender: UIButton) {
         let currentDateTime = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
       let dateTimeString = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
    timePrint1.text = dateTimeString
        
    }
    

 

    @IBOutlet weak var btnPressed1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPressed2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPressed3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPressed4: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timePrint1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timePrint2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timePrint4: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timePrint3: UILabel!
    
    
  
    

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar1: UIProgressView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar2: UIProgressView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar3: UIProgressView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar4: UIProgressView!
    
    
     let start = 5
    var timer = Timer()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    var totalTime = 0
    var secondsPassed = 0
    
    @IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
   
        let startB = sender.titleLabel?.text
        totalTime = start
           
        
        
        progressBar1.progress = 0.0
        secondsPassed = 0
        titleLabel.text = "coffee timer"
        btnPressed1.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if secondsPassed < totalTime {
            secondsPassed += 1
            progressBar1.progress = Float(secondsPassed) / Float(totalTime)
            print(Float(secondsPassed) / Float(totalTime))
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            titleLabel.text = "check coffee"
            btnPressed1.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
           
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "alarm_sound", withExtension: "mp3")
            player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
            player.play()
            
        
         
        
        }
               
    
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest multiple timers.  When you invalidate one, start the next.  They each would have their own progress update logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of different ways to handle this. Here is an outline of a possible approach:

Have an instance variable `currentProgress`, of type `Int?` If it's nil, none of your progress indicators is running.

Have an instance var `stepCompletedInterval: Double`

Create a struct to hold the different views you use to manage a progress step:

```
struct ProgressInfo {
   let aButton: UIButton
   let aLabel: UILabel
   let aProgressIndicator: UIProgressIndicator
   let secondsForThisStep: Int
}
```

Create an array of `ProgressInfo`, (let's call it `progressInfoArray`) and populate it with the buttons, labels, and progress indicators you have above. Also give each entry a value for secondsForThisStep.

When the user starts the process, set currentProgress to 0 (The first progress indicator.)

Now, for each step, set a `stepCompletedInterval` to the current time plus `progressInfoArray[currentProgress].secondsForThisStep` (The time at which the current step should complete.

Also start a 1-second repeating timer. Each time the timer fires, check to see if the current time is greater than stepCompletedInterval. If it is, increment currentProgress if there are still more steps to complete, and repeat the "now for each step" part above.

That is a rough outline of how you might go about it. I'm not completely clear on what your start buttons and `btnPressed1` to `btnPressed4` are supposed to do, so I'll leave that for you.

You'll need to adapt the approach I've outlined to your needs. It isn't code, it's an approach. I'm not going to give you code.

Comment: I don't understand half of the stuff you just said because I am new to swift.

Comment: Any time you find yourself writing multiple functions that do exactly the same thing to a different set of objects, it's a "code smell", and an indication that there's a better way to do it. Your `btnPressed1` - `btnPressed4` methods are an example of duplicate code that can be refactored.

Comment: Ok, how would I refactor them

Comment: By restructuring your code to manage an array of structs, as I described above.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: If you can't make any sense of my answer, and can't even articulate what parts of it you don't understand, I'm not sure how I can help. I think you might be trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: ok, I guess thats true

Comment: Also, I’m a 14 year old boy who’s trying to learn code so what did you expect

Comment: No judgement intended.We all have to start somewhere.  (I started programming when I was 12.) However, trying to implement complex features before you have the required language fundamentals will be frustrating and cause you to develop bad habits.